# Why does the Riemann sum of a double integral use $\Delta x, \Delta y \rightarrow 0$ as its limit instead of $m,n \rightarrow \infty $?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, riemann-integration

Edit: Let $m$ and $n$ be the number of subintervals that a region $R$ has been divided up into.

$\Delta x, \Delta y \rightarrow 0$ is equivalent to $m,n \rightarrow \infty $ because both of those limits just describe you taking smaller and smaller subrectangles of a region $R$; you take arbitrarily small subrectangles that are so small that they "approximate" the area perfectly.

So is there any reason that the Riemann sum of a double integral uses $\Delta x, \Delta y \rightarrow 0$ as its limit instead of $m,n \rightarrow \infty $ ? 
Feels like I'm missing something.

Comment: I believe they're essentially equivalent. If I understood your notation, $m$ and $n$ denote the number of subrectangles. As $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ approach $0$, the number of rectangles approaches $\infty$.

Comment: Yep that's what I mean $m$ and $n$ to denote. And okay, that's good to know then, thank you!

Comment: First of all for a general partition you don't really have one $\Delta x$. You have one $\Delta x_i$ per interval and we need all $\Delta x_i$  to go to zero to ensure convergence of the sum to the integral (and we often define $\Delta x$ to be the largest of the $\Delta x_i$'s). If you don't have equally sized intervals then there is no guarantee that $\Delta x$ goes to zero as $m\to\infty$. That only applies if all intervals have the same size.

Comment: @Winther Thank you very much! I'm having trouble understanding why there's no guarantee that $x \Delta$ may not go to zero as $m \rightarrow \infty$ if the intervals are not equally sized. Let's say all intervals except two are equally sized. One of the two is one unit smaller than the other (thus the other is a unit larger). What would happen as $m \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: What I mean is this: if the intervals are equallty sized *then* the mesh-size has to go to zero when the number of points go to infinity. Otherwise there is no guarantee (but it does not rule it out) - we need more information about the nature of the partition to determine this. The answer below gives you a concrete example of having arbitrary large number of points, but where the size of one of the intervals is always $1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Even in $\Bbb R$ you can have partitions with an arbitrarily great number of points *but* with some subinterval of constant width $> 0$. Example in $[0,1]$:
$$x_0 = 0, x_1 = 1/2, x_n = 1/2 + n/(2N), 2\le n\le N.$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure what you're getting at with this. So any set of partitions can have an arbitrarily large number of points in it? How does this relate to my question? Sorry for being slow

Comment: @JamesRonald, see the comment by Winther. I think the you are supposing that all the subintervals have the same size.